# UIWebView offline error in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview

I am loading a webpage into my app using UIWebView and following code:

```
let url = NSURL (string: "http://www.myurl.com");
let requestObj = NSURLRequest(URL: url!);
myWebView.loadRequest(requestObj);
```

I would like to hide webView if request failed for any reason, for example because of no access to internet. Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the provided delegate methods of `UIWebView`

```
func webViewDidFinishLoad(webView: UIWebView) {
    print("webview did finish load!")
}

func webView(webView: UIWebView, didFailLoadWithError error: NSError) {
    print("webview did fail load with error: \(error)")
}
```

**Note:** To use this method you need implement `UIWebViewDelegate` in your `ViewController` and set it with the webView outlet.

```
myWebView.delegate = self
```

Comment: That is exactly what I needed. Thank you.

Comment: Welcome mate, Happy Coding :)